# Emacs' `sql-mysql`, ec2

Tags: mysql, sql, emacs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Trying to get Emacs' `sql-mysql` to work with an Amazon EC2.

(Technically I think this should be in superuser, but there are 10 times more Emacs questions here, so I am guessing there are more Emacs users here.)

I have successfully used `ssh ec2-user@<elastic ip address>`, and from that command line, `mysql -u root -p` to get a successful MySQL prompt and `show databases;`. But I can't reliably get Emacs' `sql-mysql` to work (I think it worked once).

So in my ignorance, I have permuted the variables about. That is, the command `sql-mysql` prompts for `User:`, `Password:`, `Database:` and `Server:`.

For `User:` and `Password:`, I use same as I do from `ssh ec2-user@<elastic ip address>`.

For `Database:`, I have tried leaving it blank, but I think the time it worked I used `mysql`.

For `Server:`, I have tried a bunch, including

```
localhost
localhost@<elastic ip address>
ec2-user@<elastic ip address>
<elastic ip address>
```

One of the handful of error messages I get is

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

I have tried fiddling with other Emacs variables, such as `default-directory` and `sql-port`, but to no noticeable effect.

---

Additional notes:

I have tried using command line `mysql` with more options, to try to mimic the same variables, ala

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost@ec2-<elastic ip address>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com --port=3306
```

but I get unknown server host.

I have seen mention of using command `echo $db_host`, but I get nothing. This may be that I have only just initialized all of this.

I have also gone into AWS console and added a rule for MYSQL with port 3306 to security group.

Comment: Emacs just uses `mysql` underneath, so you need to figure out how to connect to the database with that from the machine that emacs runs on.  The database needs to be configured to allow outside (non-localhost) connections.  You might be able to use ssh port forwarding if there's no way to connect from the outside.

Comment: @jpkotta, Okay. Will try to add details when I get it all setup. Thank you for pointing me to the more fundamental issue. I think I was trying to use a wrench when I already had the screwdriver working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick overview of the actions you need to do:

1. Edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf in the ec2 server to allow connections from outside.  Some installations only allow localhost.  Restart mysqld server.
2. Open port 3306 from AWS console, giving access to your IP.  Make sure you can connect using "telnet IP-address 3306".  You need to see the same stuff than doing telnet localhost 3306 from the ec2 machine.
3. Create/modify mysql user so that it can connect from outside.  Some mysql installations create a root@localhost user, but this is a different user from root@your-IP.  Check that, and then doublecheck using the mysql command you wrote above.
4. Eval the code below in emacs and then do `M-x sql-connect`

Emacs should prompy you for a database to conect.  Just type "test" (emacs will autocomplete)

```
(setq sql-connection-alist
      '(("test"
         (sql-product  'mysql)
         (sql-database "your-db-name")
         (sql-server   "your-ec2-ip")
         (sql-user     "user-name")
         (sql-password "password"))))
```